# No despliega el html con el servidor Glassfish 5.0 y netbeans 8.2

Tags: java-ee

[image: Imagen de despliegue]

Cuando le doy Clean and build y luego Run al proyecto, no despliega el htlm con el "Hola mundo", y dice Glassfish Server, deploy, null, false

Comment: ¿Que error da en el server?

Comment: Grave:   Exception while deploying the app [RegistroAcademico] : JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [registroAcademicoPU], Lookup: [java:app/registroAcademicoDB], Type: [javax.sql.DataSource]

Comment: No te esta encontrando el recurso correspondiente al DataSource, ¿como lo tienes configurado?